# Owncloud broke after upgrade to 10.0.8

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, owncloud

I recently upgraded my Owncloud installation running on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS to version 10.0.8 via the builtin updater app. After I completed the upgrade and tried browsing to the site, it told me that my PHP version needed to be updated to at least version 5.6.0. So I upgraded my PHP to version 5.6.36 and not I get the following error message:

```
Exception occurred while logging exception: Failed to connect to the 

database: An exception occured in driver: could not find driver
#0 /var/www/owncloud/lib/composer/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(992): OC\DB\Connection->connect()
#1 /var/www/owncloud/lib/private/DB/Connection.php(210): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->executeUpdate('PRAGMA read_unc...', Array, Array)
#2 /var/www/owncloud/lib/composer/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(623): OC\DB\Connection->executeUpdate('PRAGMA read_unc...')
#3 /var/www/owncloud/lib/private/DB/Connection.php(145): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->setTransactionIsolation(2)
#4 /var/www/owncloud/lib/composer/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DriverManager.php(172): OC\DB\Connection->__construct(Array, Object(Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOSqlite\Driver), Object(Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration), Object(Doctrine\Common\EventManager))
#5 /var/www/owncloud/lib/private/DB/ConnectionFactory.php(146): Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection(Array, Object(Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration), Object(Doctrine\Common\EventManager))
#6 /var/www/owncloud/lib/private/Server.php(521): OC\DB\ConnectionFactory->getConnection('sqlite3', Array)
#7 /var/www/owncloud/lib/composer/pimple/pimple/src/Pimple/Container.php(113): OC\Server->OC\{closure}(Object(OC\Server))
#8 /var/www/owncloud/lib/private/AppFramework/Utility/SimpleContainer.php(111): Pimple\Container->offsetGet('DatabaseConnect...')
#9 /var/www/owncloud/lib/private/ServerContainer.php(87): OC\AppFramework\Utility\SimpleContainer->query('DatabaseConnect...')
#10 /var/www/owncloud/lib/private/Server.php(1192): OC\ServerContainer->query('DatabaseConnect...')
#11 /var/www/owncloud/lib/private/Server.php(398): OC\Server->getDatabaseConnection()
#12 /var/www/owncloud/lib/composer/pimple/pimple/src/Pimple/Container.php(113): OC\Server->OC\{closure}(Object(OC\Server))
#13 /var/www/owncloud/lib/private/AppFramework/Utility/SimpleContainer.php(111): Pimple\Container->offsetGet('AppConfig')
#14 /var/www/owncloud/lib/private/ServerContainer.php(87): OC\AppFramework\Utility\SimpleContainer->query('AppConfig')
#15 /var/www/owncloud/lib/private/Server.php(1121): OC\ServerContainer->query('AppConfig')
#16 /var/www/owncloud/lib/private/Server.php(575): OC\Server->getAppConfig()
#17 /var/www/owncloud/lib/composer/pimple/pimple/src/Pimple/Container.php(113): OC\Server->OC\{closure}(Object(OC\Server))
#18 /var/www/owncloud/lib/private/AppFramework/Utility/SimpleContainer.php(111): Pimple\Container->offsetGet('AppManager')
#19 /var/www/owncloud/lib/private/ServerContainer.php(87): OC\AppFramework\Utility\SimpleContainer->query('AppManager')
#20 /var/www/owncloud/lib/private/Server.php(1391): OC\ServerContainer->query('AppManager')
#21 /var/www/owncloud/lib/private/legacy/app.php(346): OC\Server->getAppManager()
#22 /var/www/owncloud/lib/private/legacy/app.php(110): OC_App::getEnabledApps()
#23 /var/www/owncloud/lib/base.php(579): OC_App::loadApps(Array)
#24 /var/www/owncloud/lib/base.php(997): OC::init()
#25 /var/www/owncloud/index.php(54): require_once('/var/www/ownclo...')
#26 {main}
```

The output of my php -m command shows the following:

```
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
date
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

Here are the contents of my config.php file:

```
<?php
$CONFIG = array (
  'instanceid' => 'ochvqoc7hnfv',
  'passwordsalt' => '8Nq4eSWkIepcSdmBLW8hVAyG97D3CR',
  'secret' => 'gwX4U2RzpbgIYeCcJimVRfHdck7WkfkKYCCELZioQYCWaCzM',
  'trusted_domains' =>
  array (
    0 => '192.168.20.6',
    1 => 'cloudrmsroofcom',
    2 => 'cloud.rmsroof.com',
  ),
  'datadirectory' => '/var/www/owncloud/data',
  'overwrite.cli.url' => 'http://cloud.rmsroof.com/owncloud',
  'dbtype' => 'sqlite3',
  'version' => '9.1.8.2',
  'installed' => true,
  'forcessl' => true,
  'forceSSLforSubdomains' => true,
  'ldapIgnoreNamingRules' => false,
  'loglevel' => 0,
  'maintenance' => false,
  'theme' => '',
  'trashbin_retention_obligation' => 'auto',
  'updater.secret' => '$2y$10$JgpkmF57aQX5AX0mCIYBxOjcNQJKa0hl54yRF4R9Uia6siJh5OUd2',
);
```

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Could you provide your configuration file please? Be sure to remove any password.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure exactly what you mean. I'm a bit of a novice on this OS. Can you advise?

Comment: Owncloud has a configuration file, in the `config` directory. Can you please paste its content in your question? Also, please note that Ubuntu 14.04 is old, Ubuntu 18.04 is there.

Comment: I added it to my original question. Upgrading Ubuntu was going to be my next step after my Owncloud update.

Comment: In `dbtype` are you sure `sqlite3` is a valid driver? Please try with `sqlite` only. PDO is using a DSN, so I guess the DSN is built using these informations, and I'm not sure if 'sqlite3' is a valid driver. And please hide your real tokens, passwords or IP here.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. I changed it to sqlite and saved the file, restarted apache and same error. Should sqlite be listed in my PHP modules?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171617/discussion-between-anthonyb-and-brian-fleishman).